# Running 'bower install' on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, bower, sudo, bower-install

I am trying to run `bower install` after the installation of bower using `npm` is done. But the problem is when I run `sudo bower install`, it says `bower should be run without sudo`. If one runs `bower install` it says that `permission denied cannot access file - ~/.config/configstore/bower-github.json`

I tried switching to root user but no luck. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Did you try npm install bower?

Comment: So the thing is bower is installed. But using bower I have to install some components which is not working.

Comment: run `sudo chmod 755 ~/.config/configstore/bower-github.json`

Comment: Yes I tried that. But doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be solved apparently. Run the following

```
sudo chown -R *username* ~/
```

That should solve it!